# How do I set the {userconfig} location

Tags: spring, spring-shell

From the documentation:
By default, a log file is generated to a current working directory, which you can dictate by setting spring.shell.config.location. This property can contain a placeholder ({userconfig}), which resolves to a common shared config directory.

In my application.properties I got the following:

```
spring.shell.config.location: "{userconfig}/mycli"
spring.shell.history.name: mycli.log
```

When I run my spring-shell application I get a directory tree structure that looks like this from where I ran the spring shell application:

[image]

How do I set `{userconfig}` so I actually get the log file in the location I like? I looked into the `UserConfigAutoConfiguration` class and I would think the log file should be in `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + ".config";` but it doesn't seem to work or more likely I'm doing something very wrong :-)

--Andy

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but problems is resolved. I think I messed up application.properties.